# Cassandra old data on second node

Tags: cassandra

Problem:

1.) a fast node holds data of current year by pk timestamp field.

2.) a slow but huge node holds older data.

If data will be older than a year, it will be moved to the old data node.

For a table layout like this:

```
CREATE TABLE sensor_data (
  sensor VARCHAR,
  timestamp timestamp,
  value float,
  PRIMARY KEY ((sensor), timestamp) 
)
```

If I would use the ByteOrder partioniert i can not tell the time range or i am wrong?

Comment: 1. Ordered partitioners are anti-patterns; don't use them. 2. Cassandra nodes are designed to be (equal) _peers_, so don't try to make one of them special / faster / larger / slower, etc.

Comment: I know this. But why have equal nodes if you just need the new data in 99% of all use cases?

Comment: So that your "fast" node doesn't crater handling 99% of the load while you have other, perfectly good hardware sitting idle. Balance and replicate the data around a cluster so you have (1) scalability, and (2) fault-tolerance.  Let Cassandra and the OS disk subsystem handle keeping the "hot" parts hot.  Look into [date-tiered compaction](https://labs.spotify.com/2014/12/18/date-tiered-compaction/) to help with your use case.

Comment: Thanks that sound interesting. I found a better description of  [DTCS](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy "Date-Tiered Compaction")